# Get bold keywords in the search results

Tags: php

Anyone can help me with this, i'm trying to find a right way for my case to get in bold the keywords in the search results, example, when user search for keywords 'year' in search list i need

New **Year** 2012

**Year** 2052

Good new **Year**

Here is my search function

```
$where = '';
$whereParams = array();
  if(!empty($this->query) && !$this->queue) {
  $this->logQuery();
  $where .= (empty($where) ? ' WHERE' : ' AND') . ' MATCH(d.title) AGAINST(:query)';
  $whereParams['query'] = $this->query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $bold_keyword = str_replace($keyword, '<b>'.$keyword.'</b>', $text_with_keyword);
```

Comment: or replace `<b></b>` with `<span style="font-weight:bold;"></span>`

Comment: I'm alredy try something like this
$whereParams['query'] = str_replace($this->query, '<b>'.$this->query.'</b>', $where); but this not work